# Flutter - how to display for-loop results in ListView horizontally, and how to get all the results in

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Using `ListView.Builder`I'm attempting to display for-loop results and I encounter two problems

1. It displays only one result instead of a set. (should be 12 in this example)
2. The result is been displayed vertically instead of horizontally.

I've tried to change `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,` to `Axis.horizontal`, but I run into **BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.** error which I couldn't solve either.

I already spend hours trying to figure it out and read dozens of stack overflow Q&A but to no avail nothing I tried so far worked. please help.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var sum = 25;
  String resultS = '0';
  void callForLoop() {
    print('The sum of ' '$sum' ' with 5 digits');
    for (int z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
          for (int w = 1; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
              if (z + y + x + w + v == sum) {
                if (z < y) {
                  if (y < x) {
                    if (x < w) {
                      if (w < v) {
                        String z2 = "$z";
                        String y2 = "$y";
                        String x2 = "$x";
                        String w2 = "$w";
                        String v2 = "$v";
                        setState(() {
                          print('$z + $y + $x + $w + $v');
                          resultS = ('$z2' + '+$y2' + '+$x2' + '+$w2' + '+$v2');
                        });
                        continue;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: //CustomScrollView(
                    ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, //Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: resultS.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(title: Text(resultS[index]));
                        }),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => callForLoop(),
                  child: Text('Call For Loop'),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make a list like  `List<String> resultS = [];`.

Second, Wrap `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` like

```
  Expanded(
     child: ListView.builder(
```

**Result** let me know if something else you want.

[image: scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,]

**Full Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var sum = 25;
  List<String> resultS = [];
  void callForLoop() {
    print('The sum of ' '$sum' ' with 5 digits');
    for (int z = 1; z <= 9; z++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {
          for (int w = 1; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
              if (z + y + x + w + v == sum) {
                if (z < y) {
                  if (y < x) {
                    if (x < w) {
                      if (w < v) {
                        String z2 = "$z";
                        String y2 = "$y";
                        String x2 = "$x";
                        String w2 = "$w";
                        String v2 = "$v";
                        setState(() {
                          print('$z + $y + $x + $w + $v');
                          resultS
                              .add(('$z2' + '+$y2' + '+$x2' + '+$w2' + '+$v2'));
                        });
                        continue;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: //CustomScrollView(
                    Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: resultS.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(title: Text(resultS[index]));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => callForLoop(),
                  child: Text('Call For Loop'),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Great it works, now how do I shrink the space between each set? so I don't have to scroll to see all the results?

Comment: do you mean you want fit this widget inside the screen no matter what size it becomes?

Comment: in short term. You can replace ` ListTile(title: Text(resultS[index]));` with ` Text(resultS[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning ListTile you should return a Row containing a number of widgets you want as its children for each one of the '1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ..'.